# Doubled Decimal Point in Emails on New Line

Tags: c#, email, html-email

When I send an HTML email (actually just generating .eml files rather than sending at the moment) using the .NET `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` class, it seems to be adding addition decimal points to some of my numbers.

It is only adding the extra decimal point when the number is split over a new line and the first character on the new line would have been a dot.

Input:

```
[snip]27.50[snip]137.50[snip]
```

Output:

```
[snip]27.=
50[snip]=
[snip]137=
..50[snip]
```

When opened in Outlook, the first number outputs as `27.00` but the second (understandably) outputs `137..50` (too many decimal points!)

I know the equals is a "soft line break". Is there syntax for the extra `.`?

Why is it outputting 2 dots? Can I stop it doing this?

**Non-snipped output:**

```
<tr>=0D=0A          <td>=
Units</td><td>Standard Rate</td><td></td><td>25.00</td><td>27.=
50</td><td>25.00</td><td>625.00</td><td>687.50</td>=0D=0A       </tr><=
tr>=0D=0A           <td>Timesheet Units</td><td>Standard Rate</td><td></t=
d><td>25.00</td><td>27.50</td><td>5.00</td><td>125.00</td><td>137=
..50</td>=0D=0A     </tr>
```

Comment: If my answer doesn't help, please give more details about *how* you're generating the email.

Comment: Sounds like it may be the solution. Just having a test now! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're just running into the fact that a period at the start of a line is used to terminate a mail.

From [RFC 2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt) section 4.5.2:

> 4.5.2 Transparency
>
> Without some provision for data transparency, the character sequence
>      "." ends the mail text and cannot be sent by the user.
>      In general, users are not aware of such "forbidden" sequences.  To
>      allow all user composed text to be transmitted transparently, the
>      following procedures are used:
>
> - Before sending a line of mail text, the SMTP client checks the
>     first character of the line.  If it is a period, one additional
>     period is inserted at the beginning of the line.
> - When a line of mail text is received by the SMTP server, it checks
>     the line.  If the line is composed of a single period, it is
>     treated as the end of mail indicator.  If the first character is a
>     period and there are other characters on the line, the first
>     character is deleted.

In other words, I suspect when the mail is actually *sent*, the receiver will only see one dot. It's not clear why Outlook would do the wrong thing here though...

Comment: Yes, that's the correct behaviour but I thought it would be done at the protocol level (POP3) not stored in the file. Putting it in the file looks like an accident waiting for somewhere to happen (Outlook in this case).

Comment: @david.pfx: Agreed. It's not entirely clear how the OP is generating the file - if he's doing so in a way which is *designed* to be sent over SMTP rather than stored directly in an email file, then that would definitely explain it.

Comment: Yes, I was generating it using `deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory"` so it was intended to be sent.

Comment: If you always intend to save it to a local file, you could look at [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) and use MimeKit.MimeMessage's convenience method to convert a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage into a MimeKit.MimeMessage and then save it to a file that way. By doing that, you won't get the SMTP "byte-stuffing" problem. Hope that helps.